# invalid value: continue signal on byte-three, expected a terminal signal on or before byte-three when sending a transaction

Tags: transactions, send-transaction, sendtransactionerror

I am trying to send a transaction signed via a web wallet, there is only one instruction to be executed which is to create an associated token pda. but i'm getting this response from rpc each time

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0",
"error":{
         "code":-32602,
         "message":"invalid value: continue signal on byte-three, expected a terminal 
                    signal on or before byte-three"
        },
"id":"2d232f9b-8768-472e-8a61-0c0a1a3464f9"
}
```

where can i find what this error means

Answer (score 3):

If anywone else has this issue i was using transaction.serializeMessage() instead of transaction.serialize()